# How to update a displayed variable

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
var tic;
tic = 0;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.write(tic);
</script>




<script>
var ongngic;
ongngic = 1;
</script>

<button onclick="alert(tic=tic+ongngic);">Ice Cream</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have displayed the variable "tic" with document.write. I'm not sure how to change it by clicking the id="b1" button. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the variable as well as the DOM:

- Do not use `document.write()`.
- Use a DOM Element and modify the `.innerHTML`.
- Separate HTML and JavaScript.

```js
var tic;
tic = 0;
var ongngic;
ongngic = 1;
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = tic;
function perform() {
  tic= tic + ongngic;
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = tic;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
<button onclick="perform();" type="button">Ice Cream</button>
```

Comment: thx, Praveen. But also, do you know how to do this without doing the alert?

Comment: @MarcM. Check out the updated answer. Refresh it. No alert comes now.

Comment: Wow! Thx again. Also, one more thing. Is there a way to say "Total Ice Cream:" before tic?

Comment: Replace both `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = tic;` with `document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Total Ice Cream: " + tic;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the values to HTML like below.

```
<body>
  <div id="tic_div"></div>
    <button onclick="add()">Ice Cream</button>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var tic = 0;
      var ongngic = 1;

      document.getElementById("tic_div").innerHTML = tic;

      function add(){
        tic=tic+ongngic;
        document.getElementById("tic_div").innerHTML = tic;
      }
  </script>
</body>
```